# Symfony6 Form Render Object of class App\Entity\User could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I am trying to render form of `Team` entity which is attached to User with `ManyToOne` relationship. See below Entity Class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Team
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'teams')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $owner = null;
...
```

Below is `User` entity class code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

Class User {

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: Team::class)]
    private Collection $teams;
....
```

Here is the controller class code where I am rending form view:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class TeamController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_team_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, TeamRepository $teamRepository): Response
    {
        $team = new Team();
        $form = $this->createForm(TeamType::class, $team);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $teamRepository->save($team, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_team_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('team/new.html.twig', [
            'team' => $team,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
...
```

And here is the `TeamType` form class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;


class TeamType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('intro')
            ->add('country')
            ->add('balance')
            ->add('created_at')
            ->add('updated_at')
            ->add('owner')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Team::class,
        ]);
    }
}
...
```

And lastly, the `team/new.html.twig`

```html
{% extends 'layouts/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    New Team
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <main class="container form-signin w-100 m-auto">
        <h1>Add Team</h1>

        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
        {{ form_end(form) }}


        <a href="{{ path('app_team_index') }}" class="btn btn-link bi bi-arrow-left text-decoration-none">
            &nbsp; Back to all teams</a>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting an error that `Object of class App\Entity\User could not be converted to string` exactly near the line `'form' => $form,`.

What could be a possible issue?

Comment: Can you share the `TeamType` and the `new.html.twig` template? Somewhere in the form you are rendering users, and Symfony does not now how to display them (as it cannot simply convert them to string, as the error suggests).

Comment: @Christoph - I've edited my question with `TeamType` and `team/new.html.twig`. 
It doesn't pass to the twig by the way. If I remove `$form` param, then it does.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, and great that you found the solution! Symfony is usually pretty clever in detecting the different form types you need, but when working with entities, you have to specify the details yourself. See also https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html for the different form types and their options.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. If you want to use an entity as a form field, you need to specify the class and the choice_label options in your form type. The class option tells Symfony which entity class to use for the field, and the choice_label option tells Symfony which property or method to use as the label for each choice. To fix this, you need to configure your form type for the User field like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Team;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;


class TeamType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('intro')
            ->add('country')
            ->add('balance')
            ->add('created_at')
            ->add('updated_at')
            ->add('owner', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => 'full_name', // or any other property or method that returns a string
            ]);
        ;
    }
...
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 2):

When doctrine tries to display relationships, in your case the Team and User classes. depending on the side of the relationship, doctrine tries to convert these classes to a string, in order to display select with option choice value in html form. You should be to implement __toString methods

```php
class User
{
  //...
  public function __toString()
  {
    return (string) $this->getUserIdentifier();
  }
}

class Team
{
  //...
  public function __toString()
  {
    return (string) $this->name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form will only be used to add new Teams to the [**current** User](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#fetching-the-user-object), then you should not include the owner field in the form. Instead, manually set the owner to the current User in the Controller.

So omit the `->add('owner', /*...*/);` call from your FormType and edit your handler to be something like the following (adjust for your specific Entity methods' logic):

```php
    public function new(Request $request, TeamRepository $teamRepository): Response
    {
        $team = new Team();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $user->addTeam($team);
        $team->setOwner($user);

        /* create form and handle Request */
    }
```

As an alternative to setting the owner in the handler, and especially since the owner is not nullable, you could set the owner in the Team constructor. You would then create a Team by passing the current User.